# Call to S3Client::setRegion() fails

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I'm using `"aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.0.3"` via composer to access some S3 buckets in different regions, but I can't seem to get S3Client to change regions using the `setRegion()` function without it generating the error:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to Aws\AwsClient::getCommand() must be of the type array, string given, called in vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php on line 166 and defined in vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php on line 210

Code:

```
foreach($buckets as $bucket) {
    echo 'foo' . PHP_EOL;
    $loc = $s3->getBucketLocation(['Bucket' => $bucket])['LocationConstraint'];
    var_dump($loc);
    $s3->setRegion($loc);
    echo 'bar' . PHP_EOL;
    $years = $s3->listObjects([
        'Bucket'    => $bucket,
        'Delimiter' => '/'
    ]);
    var_dump($bucket, $years);
}
```

Output:

```
foo
string(9) "us-east-1"
PHP Catchable fatal error:  {snip}
```

Notes:

- [S3Client Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html) say the method is inherited from `Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient`
- [`Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient` Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Common.Client.AbstractClient.html#_setRegion) say the function accepts a string
- But it sort of looks like this is falling through to `Aws\AwsClient::__call()` for some reason?

### edit

As @giaour said, `S3Client::setRegion()` no longer exists in the v3 client, and the documentation I'had linked was for v2. [I have no idea why it's marked as 'latest']

Here's the code that I had implemented as a workaround, which just now levelled up to 'canonical':

```
protected function s3($region='us-west-2') {
    if( ! isset($this->_clients[$region]) ) {
        $this->_clients[$region] = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
            'version' => $this->_aws_version,
            'region'  => $region,
            'credentials' => $this->credentials
        ]);
    }
    return $this->_clients[$region];
}
```

And then:

```
foreach($buckets as $bucket) {
    $region = $this->s3()->getBucketLocation(['Bucket' => $bucket])['LocationConstraint'];
    $s3 = $this->s3($region);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$s3->setRegion(['us-east-1']);`?

Comment: @Ja͢ck even worse: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Operation not found: SetRegion'` so it seems to be falling through to `__call()` and trying to fire this out to the API endpoint rather than changing the region in the client.

Comment: I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/623) on the project.

Comment: @Ja͢ck neat. Subscribed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setRegion` isn't a supported method in the version of the AWS SDK you're using. (The docs you linked to are for v2 of the SDK.)

You can create a new client and pass in the region in the constructor, e.g., `new Aws\S3\S3Client(['version' => $s3->getApi()->getApiVersion(), 'region' => $loc])`.

Comment: Crapbaskets. Well, I basically already implemented this as a workaround, so I guess it just graduated to canonical. `:I`